# The DSC Extension was not installed correctly, please check the logs on the VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, ms-release-management

I was trying to Install an extension called "Visual Studio Release Managment" to my Azure VM. Then I checked the log files in the Azure VM:

> VERBOSE: [2015-12-10T14:22:33] File lock does not exist: begin
>   processing VERBOSE: [2015-12-10T14:22:33] Reading handler environment
>   from 
>   C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.10.1.0\bin..\HandlerEnvironment.json
>   VERBOSE: [2015-12-10T14:22:36] [ERROR] The DSC Extension was not
>   installed correctly, please check the logs on the VM 
>   (C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.10.1.0)
>   VERBOSE: [2015-12-10T14:22:38] Writing handler status to
>   C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.10.1.0\Status\0.status
>   VERBOSE: [2015-12-10T14:22:39] Removing file lock

And Here is a Photo of the error: [Error Azure Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BM3f.png)